# Sharing a List of(String) between Private Sub

Tags: vb.net, sharing

In my code I basically read a textbox and put each line into a list (Of String) *Dim "testblock" in code below*

From there I create another list (of string) and split each line whenever a space is found. *Dim "block" in code below*

Now I want to be able to access that list from anywhere in the project.

How do I go about sharing a List of(String) between Private Sub such as form buttons?

```
Private Sub PhaseCodeBTN_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PhaseCodeBTN.Click
    Dim testblock As New List(Of String)
    Dim lines As String() = TextBox1.Text.Split(New String() {Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    Dim block As New List(Of String)

    For Each l As String In lines
        testblock.Add(l)
        Dim words As String() = BlockCodeBox.Text.Split(" ")
        For Each splitword As String In words
            block.Add(splitword)
        Next
    Next
    BlockCodeBox.Text = testblock(BlockNumBox.Text)
    WordCmdBox.Text = block(WordNumBox.Text)

End Sub

Private Sub PhaseBlackBTN_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PhaseBlackBTN.Click

    WordCmdBox.Text = block(WordNumBox.Text)
End Sub
```

Comment: declare it outside that click event.  As is, since it is declared in that sub it only exists there - it is called `Scope`.  If you declare it at the form or class level, all procs can use it - it will have module (form/class) level `Scope`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I knew about that way but wanted it more on a protective level. I just re wrote the code into a class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `Public Shared Class` with your `List(Of String)` there to use it anywhere in the project:

```
Public Shared Class DataHolder

    Private _block As New List(Of String)

    Public Property Block As List(Of String)
    Get
        Return _block
    End Get        
    Set
        _block = value
    End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

**Example:**

Either simply use `DataHolder.Block.Add(splitword)` OR following steps:

1. Declare a class variable `block` to use it in entire class:

   ```
   Private block As List(Of String)
   ```
2. Initialize it in some suitable function / event-handler like  `Form_Load`:

   ```
   block = DataHolder.Block
   ```
3. Do the operation:

   ```
   block.Add(splitword)
   ```

Comment: ```Public Shared Class``` is not VB. In VB that is called a ```Public Module```.

Comment: @Christoph OP asked for VB.NET solution not VB.

Comment: That's what I ment of course (in my usage of every day language VB stands for VB.NET, traditional VB would be VB6). But here again explicit to avoid confustion: ```Public Shared Class``` is not _VB.NET_. In _VB.NET_ that is called a ```Public Module```. ```Public Shared Class``` is an incorrect translation of C#'s ```public static class```.

Comment: @Christoph Module is not Class and is global to application. You can either make `Public Module` but that is NOT class OR you can make a `Public Class` and mark its class members `Shared`. Answer was like pseudo code, one can translate it to specific language.